# TinyMCE gem is not working in my rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tinymce

I am trying to use tinyMCE gem in my rail 3 application. I cant see all the options on editor like
I cant see-
1.Style (Option is visible but can not drop down)
2. cant insert image (A button to browse image is not visible on the selection window)
3. I cant see any other option for table, enlarge screen, font type etc.

Please help me if anybody has any solution.
Thank you.

Comment: I did the following thinks....
1.In my GemFile added:
gem 'tinymce-rails'

2. Created a config/tinymce.yml:
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen

3. Include the TinyMCE assets:
//= require tinymce

4. In my view:
<%= text_area_tag :editor, "", :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>

Please help me I am not getting anything whats going on...
Thankz in advance.

Comment: Please help me to get out of it..

Comment: Did you call <%= tinymce %>?

Comment: Yes I called in my view after text_area_tag.
plz help for the same

Comment: @Eraden: Plz help me Eraden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this configuration everything works fine. If you have other language make sure that you have this language in your assets repository. If you don't tiny throw exception and break creating table with buttons.

template file:

```
<%= text_area_tag :editor, "", :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>
<input type="file" id="image_uploader" style="display:none;opacity:0;" />
<%= tinymce %>
```

Styles fix (predefine styles):
config/tinymce.yml

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
style_formats:
  - title: 'Bold text'
    inline: 'b'
  - title: 'Red text'
    inline: 'span'
    styles:
      color : '#ff0000'
file_browser_callback: 'file_upload'
```

Javascript (file in your assets):

```js
(function(){
// encapsulating
  var iu = document.getElementById('image_uploader');
  iu.addEventListener('change',send_after_choose);

  function send_after_choose(event){
    // some multipart ajax U need to create new FormData see documentation of use
    // when done fetch url
  }
  // this need to be global function.
  function file_upload(field_name, url, type, win){
    var iu = document.getElementById('image_uploader');
    iu.click();
  }
  window.file_upload=file_upload;
})();
```

More information is no: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser

Sorry, but this is very large part of code to write and I haven't working example so U must write it yourself. But after adding this code U will be able to see file button in your image popup and he will call function you wrote.

I don't known which framework U use so I wrote little simple of vanila javascript. On change event works fine with file input. Input can be invisible, U can add it whenever U want as long as he hasn't name.

Data object documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

If U use jQuery U can add FormData object as request data. I don't know how this works with Mootools or Prototype.

Comment: Thank you very very much Eraden.
But please help me for one more thing, when I click on image icon in tinyMCE a browes button is missing please help me for this time. And if any other options are there please suggest me.
Thank you very much

Comment: U means U can't upload image, yes? This is more complicated problem, because U must create popup. Maybe this is not so simple. I will add U basic information.

Comment: Can you please help me to write code for file upload....for
function file_upload(field_name, url, type, win){
  /* Src */
}

Comment: Ok, U must create form with file button or connect this function with invisible one and simulate click it by calling input.click(). After that U should see standard file manager window. After U choose file U should send this file to server, save and return url to file. If I am correct input should send event 'onchange' when U choose file. All other tasks should be easy handled by tinymce.

Comment: var cmsURL = window.location.toString();
Instead 
Please tel me path to open my system path to select image from my desktop.

Comment: No, this return U your current location. I updated my respond above and add necessary code.

Comment: I did same thing it gives iu.click(); is null when i use firebug. plz help

Comment: TypeError: iu is null
[Break On This Error]  

iu.click();

Comment: Look above. I add `document.get...` for file_upload. U have very little expirience with js, aren't u? :)

Comment: TypeError: f is undefined
return f.apply(s || t, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
This is the erron and also table cant be inserted. Please suggest

Comment: Eraden I tried very much even I tried ckeditor, tinyMCE, nicedit but same problem persist plz help me for tinyMCE that image button doest work I am unable to find the way. Please